# hive table created from parquet file not showing any data, even though data is there in parquet file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hive, parquet, hue

I have a parquet file location which has data.
using HUE , i created a hive table as below

```
create external table parq_test ( 
  A int,
  B int,
  C int
  )
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/data/parq_test';
```

when I say

```
select * from parq_test;
```

It is returning 0 rows.

I tried this

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE parq_test;
```

still no luck

below i tried but it is not supporting in my HUE console

```
ALTER TABLE parq_test RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

> Infact i test in my notebook , there is data available in my parquet
>   file. So what is wrong here , why my table does not show any data ?

Comment: is the location for hadoop or local file system?

Comment: MSCK REPAIR TABLE parq_test?

Comment: can you please share the full path to parquet files? What is after this path /data/parq_test?

Comment: Your table is not partitioned, MSCK REPAIR will not have any impact. Under the assumption that columns you defined in the table are the same like the schema of the parquet files try to use a full path hdfs://<hostname>/data/parq_test/ in LOCATION

Comment: @BdEngineer, exactly. And it will only work if your table contains PARTITIONED BY part and there are Hive style folders names like year=2020/month=02/day=14, instead of 2020/02/14

Answer (score 2):

The column names in parquet file & the hive table should match, then only you can see the data using your Hive query for the specific columns. If not, you will see the rows with NULL values for those columns.

Let me show you how it writes in step-by-step instruction:

1)Create a Hive table with columns (id, name)

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kmdb.test_ext_parquet (id STRING, name STRING) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet';
No rows affected (0.178 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SELECT * FROM kmdb.test_ext_parquet;
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| test_ext_parquet.id  | test_ext_parquet.name  |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
No rows selected (0.132 seconds)
```

2)Write a Parquet file: I create a spark dataframe with same column names (id,name) & write a parque file.

```
>>> dataDF=spark.createDataFrame([("1", "aaa"), ("2", "bbb")]) \
...  .toDF("id", "name")
>>> 
>>> dataDF.show(200, False)
+---+----+                                                                      
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |aaa |
|2  |bbb |
+---+----+

>>> dataDF.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').parquet("/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet")
>>>
```

3)Validate the data

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SELECT * FROM kmdb.test_ext_parquet;
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| test_ext_parquet.id  | test_ext_parquet.name  |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| 1                    | aaa                    |
| 2                    | bbb                    |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
2 rows selected (0.219 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

4)Now write parquet file with different column names (id2,name2) using Spark dataframe

```
>>> dataDF2=spark.createDataFrame([("101", "ggg"), ("102", "hhh")]) \
...  .toDF("id2", "name2")
>>> 
>>> dataDF2.show(200, False)
+---+-----+
|id2|name2|
+---+-----+
|101|ggg  |
|102|hhh  |
+---+-----+

>>> 
>>> dataDF2.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').parquet("/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet")
>>>
```

5)Let's query table to see the data, see NULL values for the columns.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SELECT * FROM kmdb.test_ext_parquet;
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| test_ext_parquet.id  | test_ext_parquet.name  |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| 1                    | aaa                    |
| NULL                 | NULL                   |
| 2                    | bbb                    |
| NULL                 | NULL                   |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
4 rows selected (0.256 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

6)Now, I will write parquet file with just one correct column name (id), other one is non-existing(name2).

```
>>> dataDF3=spark.createDataFrame([("201", "xxx"), ("202", "yyy")]) \
...  .toDF("id", "name2")
>>> 
>>> dataDF3.show(200, False)
+---+-----+
|id |name2|
+---+-----+
|201|xxx  |
|202|yyy  |
+---+-----+

>>> 
>>> dataDF3.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').parquet("/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet")
>>>
```

7)Let's query table to see the data, see NULL values for the incorrect columns.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SELECT * FROM kmdb.test_ext_parquet;
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| test_ext_parquet.id  | test_ext_parquet.name  |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
| NULL                 | NULL                   |
| NULL                 | NULL                   |
| 1                    | aaa                    |
| 2                    | bbb                    |
| 201                  | NULL                   |
| 202                  | NULL                   |
+----------------------+------------------------+--+
6 rows selected (0.225 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

8)Now how do we read the "hidden" data? Just create a table with all columns.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kmdb.test_ext_parquet_all_columns (id STRING, name STRING,id2 STRING, name2 STRING)
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .>  STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet';
No rows affected (0.097 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SELECT * FROM  kmdb.test_ext_parquet_all_columns;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--+
| test_ext_parquet_all_columns.id  | test_ext_parquet_all_columns.name  | test_ext_parquet_all_columns.id2  | test_ext_parquet_all_columns.name2  |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--+
| NULL                             | NULL                               | 101                               | ggg                                 |
| NULL                             | NULL                               | 102                               | hhh                                 |
| 1                                | aaa                                | NULL                              | NULL                                |
| 2                                | bbb                                | NULL                              | NULL                                |
| 201                              | NULL                               | NULL                              | xxx                                 |
| 202                              | NULL                               | NULL                              | yyy                                 |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--+
6 rows selected (0.176 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

Now, how do I know what all columns are there in the parquet file(s)??? I can do by reading the parquet file(s) using Spark:

```
>>> spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/km_hadoop/data/test_ext_parquet").show(10,False)
+----+-----+----+----+
|id2 |name2|id  |name|
+----+-----+----+----+
|101 |ggg  |null|null|
|102 |hhh  |null|null|
|null|xxx  |201 |null|
|null|yyy  |202 |null|
|null|null |1   |aaa |
|null|null |2   |bbb |
+----+-----+----+----+

>>>
```

I hope this helped..